# Problems transferring photos and videos from iPhone to PC

Tags: windows, file-transfer, desktop-computer, iphone, photos

I have an iphone 12 mini that won't easily transfer photos and videos to free up space.  As a result, I can't install any new apps or use the camera, and I'm constantly deleting thing I don't really want to delete.

When I plug the phone in to the PC via the USB cable, Windows recognizes it as a drive and it begins loading preview images in file explorer, but it loses the connection before I can transfer anything.  I get the message "The device is unreachable", even though the phone still shows it is charging.  This happens with both of my computers, running Windows 8 and Windows 10.  I've tried using different cables and different ports, with no success.

I've discovered I can save photos one at a time to iCloud files, visit my iCloud drive via my PC's web browser, and download each file individually.  The problem here is that without going through the cable transfer, the files maintain their original, weird Apple file types and aren't converted to more recognizable types.  I can use Gimp to export each photo to a normal .png from the bizarre .heic format the iphone uses, but the whole process is extremely time-consuming.  Furthermore, the videos don't play at all (even though they're .mov), and I don't have a way to convert them since nothing I have recognizes the encoding.

The most recent thing I've tried is saving the files to icloud, opening the "Files" app on my old iphone (which doesn't have the "unreachable" problem), and trying to transfer to the PC that way.  This works for photos, but not for videos, since the icloud UI on the older iphone doesn't give me an option for "Save Video".

Has anyone else run into the "device unreachable" problem while transferring files, and is there a work-around?

Is there a way to easily get files off my iphone without a cable and get them into a PC-friendly format?

Comment: Use one of these methods to free up space: https://support.apple.com/en-om/guide/iphone/iphf2d851b9/ios

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/80653/offline-batch-conversion-of-heic-to-jpg-while-preserving-metadata-exif

Comment: [iOS supports wireless synchronization with iTunes. Have you tried that solution? Windows Photo actually supports HEIC. Have you considered the device needs to be serviced in order for data transfer to be successful?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463538/how-to-browse-the-iphone-heic-images-on-windows-without-the-automatic-conversion)

Comment: When you log into iCloud  on your computer to see your stuff, (a) you should be able to multiple select to download (I can) and then (b) delete from iCloud. This deletes from your iPhone as well. I do this to make sure my permanent stuff is on my computer and backed up.

Comment: Do you have iTunes? iTunes itself won't import photos, but it will enable proper backup & sync. It will also enable Windows' own Photos app to do the import. You can choose on the phone whether to convert to jpg or not, but Photos has an HEIC plugin that can view them. There's no need any more to do this as a 'removable storage file transfer', like back in the Win7 days. See https://support.apple.com/HT201302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen before when one of the files on my iphone was corrupt.

Try this.  When the file explorer opens, change the view from "icons" to "details".  That should stop explorer from trying to read every file and just present you with a directory listing.

From there, grab a few files at a time and copy them to your hard drive.  Repeat until you either copy all files, or run into the file causing the problem.

I've also seen this if you try to copy the entire DCIM folder.  It chokes on that.  Go at least one level into the DCIM folder and begin copying files from there.

Once you have all of your pictures copied to your PC, then delete them from the phone.

Comment: The iPhone will do the conversion for you if you import via the MS Photos app, not file transfer from the DCIM folder.

Comment: This didn't completely fix the issue, but reducing the icons to below thumbnail size buys me enough time to transfer a few videos before the phone stops responding and I need to unplug and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a very neat wireless solution for transferring files between iOS and PC or Mac.

It's called [Documents: File Manager & Docs by Readdle Technologies](https://apps.apple.com/app/id364901807).

Essentially, it turns your iPhone into a temporary FTP Server, allowing you to connect to it via the web-browser on your computer. From there, you can download or upload files to and from the device.

I'm not sure if there is a "delete files from device after transfer", but I wouldn't be surprised if they have covered that option as well.

I highly recommend giving it a go. It should completely bypass the unreachable error you have when cable connecting. I was able to perform my transfers without paying the "Documents Plus" premium subscription, but if you find your needs can only be met with plus, then they offer a free trial you can use for the time being as well.

For batch converting files to a more friendly format i would give [Irfhan View](https://www.irfanview.com/) a go. With this app you can set your input/output options and set an almost limitless amount of files to convert and then walk away. After installing the [main app](https://www.fosshub.com/IrfanView.html?dwl=iview462_x64_setup.exe), be sure to also install the [IrfhanView Plugins](https://www.irfanview.net/plugins/formats_64.zip) as well. The plugins add further support for a much wider range of file types.